# windows service after starting exception

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed a windows service. When I debug the service, it works fine.

But when I install it & start the service it throws exception for `datetime` when storing into the MYSQL database. Since the format of the datetime on my system is different from the one on the MySQL database.

My system `datetime` format is `mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss`. MYSQL does not accept this `mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt` format for the datetime column

which format will be chosen by window service?

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL parameters to transfer date/time values. This way, you can simply pass a datetime object instead of its string representation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt`

Answer (score -1):

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) for details on formatting the DateTime, see the example at the bottom of the page.

Quote from page:

```
// This example displays the following output to the console:
//       d: 6/15/2008
//       D: Sunday, June 15, 2008
//       f: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15 PM
//       F: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15:07 PM
//       g: 6/15/2008 9:15 PM
//       G: 6/15/2008 9:15:07 PM
//       m: June 15
//       o: 2008-06-15T21:15:07.0000000
//       R: Sun, 15 Jun 2008 21:15:07 GMT
//       s: 2008-06-15T21:15:07
//       t: 9:15 PM
//       T: 9:15:07 PM
//       u: 2008-06-15 21:15:07Z
//       U: Monday, June 16, 2008 4:15:07 AM
//       y: June, 2008
//       
//       'h:mm:ss.ff t': 9:15:07.00 P
//       'd MMM yyyy': 15 Jun 2008
//       'HH:mm:ss.f': 21:15:07.0
//       'dd MMM HH:mm:ss': 15 Jun 21:15:07
//       '\Mon\t\h\: M': Month: 6
//       'HH:mm:ss.ffffzzz': 21:15:07.0000-07:00
```